# recvmsg() blocking on the first call but not on subsequent calls

Tags: c, sockets, linux-kernel, client-server, netlink

I am having a problem with my client-server C program.

There are 2 main parts to the program. In part one, a message is sent from a Kernel module to a Userspace listener via multicast. I have tried and tested this part of the program many times and it works as expected.

The second part of the program transfers the message received to another machine (Machine 2). So, the Userspace listener from Machine 1 gets the message from the Kernel and then acts as a Client, opening up a socket between Machine 1 and Machine 2. The Server in Machine 2 receives the message and prints it to stdout. It then waits for another message.

The issue seems to be that the recvmsg() function blocks the first time but not in subsequent iterations. It is as if the information in the socket stays there and therefore prevents recvmsg() from blocking. The result is that the same piece of information is transferred in a loop.

I could be wrong on this recvmsg() problem. Perhaps someone has more experience and can point me in the right direction. The code and output are below. Many thanks.

**NetLinkUser_Client.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <linux/netlink.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#define MAX_PAYLOAD 1024
#define MY_GROUP    1
#define OUT_PORT "5001"
#define OUT_IP "192.168.xxx.xxx"

void client(char *msg) {
   int socketfd, portno, n;
   struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
   struct hostent *server;

   portno = atoi(OUT_PORT);

   /* Create a socket point */
   socketfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

   if (socketfd < 0) {
      perror("ERROR opening socket");
      exit(1);
   }

   server = gethostbyname(OUT_IP);

   if (server == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
      exit(0);
   }

   bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
   serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);
   serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

   /* Now connect to the server */
   if (connect(socketfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
      perror("ERROR connecting");
      exit(1);
   }

   /* Now send a message to the server, this message
          * will be read by server
        */
    char buffer[MAX_PAYLOAD];
    bzero(buffer,MAX_PAYLOAD);
    strcpy(buffer, msg);

    printf("\nThe contents of the buffer is: %s\n", buffer);

    printf("\nThe length of the buffer is: %d\n", strlen(buffer));

    /* Send message to the server */
    n = write(socketfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));

    if (n < 0) {
      perror("ERROR writing to socket");
      exit(1);
    }

    bzero(buffer,MAX_PAYLOAD);
    printf("%s\n",buffer);

    close(socketfd);
}
int main(void)
{
    int sock_fd;
    struct sockaddr_nl user_sockaddr;
    struct nlmsghdr *nl_msghdr;
    struct msghdr msghdr;
    struct iovec iov;

    char* kernel_msg;

    sock_fd = socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_USERSOCK);
    if(sock_fd<0)
    {
        printf("Error creating socket because: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }


    memset(&user_sockaddr, 0, sizeof(user_sockaddr));
    user_sockaddr.nl_family = AF_NETLINK;
    user_sockaddr.nl_pid = getpid();
    user_sockaddr.nl_groups = MY_GROUP; 

    bind(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&user_sockaddr, sizeof(user_sockaddr));
    while (1) {
        ssize_t recvmsg_err = 0;
        nl_msghdr = (struct nlmsghdr*) malloc(NLMSG_SPACE(1024));
        memset(nl_msghdr, 0, NLMSG_SPACE(1024));


        // The issue is not related to zeroing out msghdr
        printf("The struct member msghdr.msg_namelen has the value : %d before zeroing out\n", msghdr.msg_namelen);
        memset(&msghdr, 0, sizeof(msghdr));
        printf("The struct member msghdr.msg_namelen has the value : %d after zeroing out\n", msghdr.msg_namelen);

        memset(&iov, 0, sizeof(iov));

        iov.iov_base = (void*) nl_msghdr;
        iov.iov_len = NLMSG_SPACE(1024);

        msghdr.msg_name = (void*) &user_sockaddr;
        msghdr.msg_namelen = sizeof(user_sockaddr);
        msghdr.msg_iov = &iov;
        msghdr.msg_iovlen = 1;

        printf("The struct member msghdr.msg_namelen has the value : %d after initialization\n", msghdr.msg_namelen);
        printf("Waiting to receive message\n");

        // Execution not pausing here WHY??
        printf("recvmsg() should wait here\n");
        recvmsg_err = recvmsg(sock_fd, &msghdr, 0);

        if(recvmsg_err == -1)
        {
            perror("Error in recvmsg\n");
        }

        printf("The value returned by recvmsg() is %d\n", recvmsg_err);

        kernel_msg = (char*)NLMSG_DATA(nl_msghdr);
        printf("Kernel message: %s\n", kernel_msg); // print to android logs
        client(kernel_msg);

    }
    close(sock_fd);
}
```

**MsgServer.c**

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#include <string.h>
#define MAX_PAYLOAD 1024
void doprocessing (int sock) {
   int n;
   char buffer[MAX_PAYLOAD];
   bzero(buffer,MAX_PAYLOAD);
   n = read(sock,buffer,MAX_PAYLOAD);

   if (n < 0) {
      perror("ERROR reading from socket");
      exit(1);
   }
   printf("The length of the buffer is %d\n", strlen(buffer));
   printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);

}
int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
   int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, clilen;
   char buffer[1024];
   struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
   int n, pid;

   /* First call to socket() function */
   sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

   if (sockfd < 0) {
      perror("ERROR opening socket");
      exit(1);
   }

   /* Initialize socket structure */
   bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
   portno = 5001;

   serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
   serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

   /* Now bind the host address using bind() call.*/
   if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
      perror("ERROR on binding");
      exit(1);
   }

   /* Now start listening for the clients, here
      * process will go in sleep mode and will wait
      * for the incoming connection
   */

   listen(sockfd,5);
   clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

   while (1) {
      printf("Waiting for initial connection in doProcessing() while loop\n");
      newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);

      if (newsockfd < 0) {
         perror("ERROR on accept");
         exit(1);
      }

      /* Create child process */
      pid = fork();

      if (pid < 0) {
         perror("ERROR on fork");
         exit(1);
      }

      if (pid == 0) {
         /* This is the client process */
         close(sockfd);
         doprocessing(newsockfd);
         exit(0);
      }
      else {
         close(newsockfd);
      }

   } /* end of while */
}
```

**Client sample output**

```
The struct member msghdr.msg_namelen has the value : 12 before zeroing out
The struct member msghdr.msg_namelen has the value : 0 after zeroing out
The struct member msghdr.msg_namelen has the value : 12 after initialization
Waiting to receive message
recvmsg() should wait here
The value returned by recvmsg() is 72
Kernel message: Progger:7,root,1537,1533,1261,4s,192.168.xxx.xxx,5001


The contents of the buffer is: Progger:7,root,1537,1533,1261,4s,192.168.xxx.xxx,5001


The length of the buffer is: 54

The struct member msghdr.msg_namelen has the value : 12 before zeroing out
The struct member msghdr.msg_namelen has the value : 0 after zeroing out
The struct member msghdr.msg_namelen has the value : 12 after initialization
Waiting to receive message
recvmsg() should wait here
The value returned by recvmsg() is 72
Kernel message: Progger:7,root,1537,1533,1261,4s,192.168.xxx.xxx,5001


The contents of the buffer is: Progger:7,root,1537,1533,1261,4s,192.168.xxx.xxx,5001


The length of the buffer is: 54
```

**Server Sample Output**

```
Waiting for initial connection in doProcessing() while loop
The length of the buffer is 54
Here is the message: Progger:7,root,1537,1533,1261,4s,192.168.xxx.xxx,5001

Waiting for initial connection in doProcessing() while loop
The length of the buffer is 54
Here is the message: Progger:7,root,1537,1533,1261,4s,192.168.xxx.xxx,5001

Waiting for initial connection in doProcessing() while loop
The length of the buffer is 54
Here is the message: Progger:7,root,1537,1533,1261,4s,192.168.xxx.xxx,5001

Waiting for initial connection in doProcessing() while loop
The length of the buffer is 54
Here is the message: Progger:7,root,1537,1533,1261,4s,192.168.xxx.xxx,5001
```

I understand that this might be hard to reproduce considering Netlink is involved. Thanks in advance for your help and sorry for the long post.

Edit: I have changed the code to check for errors in recvmsg() as was suggested but the output is exactly the same.

Comment: You're not checking for returned errors. Any further debugging effort is a waste of time. The system probably tells you what's wrong but you ignore it.

Comment: So it recv'ed message from the kernel the second time, isn't that expected? What's the problem?

Comment: @fluter The Kernel module is designed to send messages based on certain conditions. The message will be different every time. The issue here is that the same message is being sent every time. As I state in my question. I have tested the Kernel module separately and it works as expected. It sends different condition dependent messages each time.

Comment: @Art Thanks for your suggestion. I have added error checking for recvmsg() but the output is the same.

Comment: Just one glance for the usual suspects shows 'printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);' called on a buffer that is not guaranteed null-terminated.

Comment: So to be clear, `recvmsg()` is returning a positive value?

Comment: @EJP Yes. I have edited the question code and output again to reflect this. Thanks.

Comment: @MartinJames I have confirmed the length of the strings on both client and server sides using the strlen() function. As you know, this function counts the characters upto but not including the null character. I edited the code and showed the output.

Comment: @S.Gill checking for the `NULL` terminator using `strlen` is a dud (won't do what you expect). The `NULL` and content might be there from a previous `recv` while `recv` wrote `0` bytes to the buffer. Notice, when no bytes are written, the `buffer` will remain the same. Also, a `NULL` will **not** get written by `recv`

Comment: @S.Gill *What* 'null character'? The correct way to delimit the received message is with the positive value returned by `recvmsg()`. That's what it is *for.* You should not be messing around with nulls or `strlen()` or `memset()` at all. You will find when you do this properly that you aren't missing any data at all.

Comment: @EJP How do you mean though? When I test this code, just receiving the message from the Kernel (No transfer to machine 2), a new message is produced every time. However, when I add in the client-server-transfer part, the message received from the Kernel gets "stuck" for want of a better word. How does adding in the client-server-transfer part make a difference? Thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: I have solved the problem. In fact @EJP was correct, no data was being lost. The code works fine. The issue was that the Kernel module was monitoring network connections. I know I did not add this in to the question and so you could not have answered. Because of the creation and recreation of sockets, the same message was produced again and again. I altered the Kernel module to ignore the socket connection related to this c program. Now it works as I had expected. Sorry to waste your time. I did learn some things from your input though. Thanks